# How to read custom config section in app.config in c#

Tags: c#, app-config, configsection

I want to read following custom section from app.config:

```
<StartupFolders>    
   <Folders name="a">
      <add folderType="Inst" path="c:\foo" />
      <add folderType="Prof" path="C:\foo1" />      
   </Folders>
   <Folders name="b">
      <add folderType="Inst" path="c:\foo" />
      <add folderType="Prof" path="C:\foo1" />      
   </Folders> 
</StartupFolders>
```

I found [this link](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2006/11/13/app-config-and-custom-configuration-sections.aspx), but it does not say for multiple `<Folders>` tag. Please help?

Comment: Please post you code and explain how it does not work for you. As it stands, this is a very poor quality question and should be closed.

Comment: Did you check out some of the links I posted in my answer to your earlier question?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642247/how-can-we-write-our-own-configuration-in-app-config  Those links would explain how to write a custom config section and how to read and use it, too

Answer (score 2):

Hi You can Access custom sections like this

```
CustomConfigClass section = (CustomConfigClass)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("StartupFolders");
```

Hope it helps you.